# Connecting Laravel with SQL Server database always shows error "could not find driver"

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laragon

I want to connect Laravel (version 8), with a SQL Server database (SQL Server 2008 R2).

I've done the installation and followed some tutorials with steps like the [following](https://ozkadon.blogspot.com/2018/10/tutorial-laravel-55-menghubungkan-laravel-dengan-database-sql-server.html), where the version I installed adapts to SQL Server 2008 R2, like [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) :

1. Installed Microsoft® ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (I chose version 17 because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#odbc-driver))
2. Installed PHP Driver version 5.6 by taking 2 files, namely `php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll` which I got from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.1) (I chose version 5.6 based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2016#%20sql-server-version-certified-compatibility))
3. I put the above 2 files in `C:\larragon\bin\php\php-7.3.9-Win32-VC15-x64\ext`
4. I enabled the extension in `php.ini`, like this: `extension=pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts`,
   `extension=sqlsrv_73_ts`. It succeed, When I checked in `php.info`, it says `pdo_sqlsrv`
5. Then I configured the database connection on Laravel's `.env` like this (*I've created a database with that name*):

> ```
> DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
> DB_HOST=192.168.101.103:86
> DB_PORT=1433
> DB_DATABASE=testlaravel
> DB_USERNAME=faisallocal
> DB_PASSWORD=faisallocal
> ```

6. Then I run `php artisan migrate` on terminal.

But I always get an error like this:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id =
> object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))
>
> at
> C:\larragon\www\redeempointappapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
> 708▕ // If an exception occurs when trying to run a query, we'll format the error
> 709▕ // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 710▕ // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 711▕ catch (Exception $e) {   712▕ throw new QueryException(
> 713▕ $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 714▕ );
> 715▕ }
> 716▕ }
>
> 1
> C:\larragon\www\redeempointappapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
> PDOException::("could not find driver")
>
> 2
> C:\larragon\www\redeempointappapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
> PDO::__construct("dblib:host=192.168.101.103:86:1433;dbname=testlaravel;charset=utf8",
> "faisallocal", "faisallocal", [])]

What did I miss?
I did this test locally, and **I have XAMPP as well as Laragon with different versions**, but wouldn't it be okay if I had a different port?

Please help anyone who has experience and has advice on this, I've been stuck at this point for weeks..

Thank you

Comment: Hi Muhammad, 

Just a recommendation to ease your setup.Take a look into Laragon for laravel development on windows.

Comment: Yes thanks for the recoomendation, but I don't know even though I've followed the steps from the tutorial, the error still appears. and I'm confused how to debug it..

Comment: What is the reason for MSSQL? 

Normalwise PHP and mySQL goes hand in hand. 

https://laragon.org/

One click installer, will make your life much easier :D

Comment: I have this error too, trying to figure out what is this....

Comment: Ok, in my case there was an error in the migration file. Check the code, or share it with us.

Comment: @AndreasTherkildsen Yes I agree it's more familiar, but this is just what my company needs..

Comment: @RobyB I solved the problem, after I left it for a long time, I will describe it in the answer field. Of course if there is no problem with the db migration, then writing to the db will not be a problem. But it's a problem in the php version, which is causing all the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this all happened because of the detected different versions of PHP and SQL Server drivers.

For information, I have 3 local servers, namely:

1. XAMPP 1.7.3,
2. XAMPP 3.?.? (*I forgot the version details*),
3. and Laragon.

The problem that occurs is, when I want to develop apps using the Laragon server **AND** I use the local Terminal/Command Prompt (*Shortcut: Windows + CMD*), the PHP versions from other local servers will collide with each other.

When I run a Laravel command, check the PHP version, or whatever, the local Command Prompt directs me to the version of XAMPP above that I have installed, so any `.dll` or plugins you install in Laragon won't be detected!

Finally I was able to finish my installation and do a lot of CMD commands according to the version I want, is how to use the built-in CMD/Terminal from Laragon (*Click on Terminal under Laragon application*)

From this Terminal, all the `.dll` plugins that you install, and all the cmd commands that you enter, will match the Laragon version you are using, they won't be strayed to another local server! :D

Answer (score 0):

php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll  It depends of your version of php

for example: php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll is for php 7.3

in the next link you can see this information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: My problem is probably because I have multiple Apache servers on my local machine. I have XAMPP with version 1.7.3, version 3.5 (if I'm not mistaken), and Laragon with a customizable version. I tried using Laragon, maybe from there the configuration is not detected and error